# How can you get the selected option of a dropdown with Playwright

Tags: c#, webautomation, playwright, playwright-sharp

I am using the C# Language Bindings of Playwright.

Example HTML:

```html
<select id="txtType" name="Type" class="form-control">
        <option>Blog Posts</option>
        <option>Books</option>
        <option>Presentations</option>
        <option>Videos</option>
        <option>Podcasts</option>
        <option>Examples</option>
</select>
```

I know that I can use `Page.SelectOptionAsync` to set the selected option for the dropdown, but how do I get the currently selected ones?

When I have a look at all of the properties of the DropDown, I can't see any difference in the `ElementHandles`.

Comment: If it is for evaluation / assertion only, then there is expect [to_have_value](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value)

Answer (score 7):

```
<select id="element_id">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
<select>
```

For NodeJS Playwright

To get the selected option `value` (2) from the dropdown:

```
await page.$eval('#element_id', sel => sel.value)
```

To get the selected option `text` ("Option 2") from the dropdown:

```
await page.$eval('#element_id', sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].textContent)
```

---

For C# just wrap the second argument in quotes:

```
await page.EvalOnSelectorAsync<string>("#element_id", "sel => sel.value")
await page.EvalOnSelectorAsync<string>("#element_id", "sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].textContent")
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, here's a nicer option for NodeJS Playwright, in my opinion, using the [locator evaluate function](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-evaluate):

```
  test('should render correctly', async () => {
    // act
    await page.goto('http://localhost:' + localPort);

    // assert
    async function extractSelectedDisplayedValue(selectedOption) {
      return selectedOption.evaluate(sel => sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].textContent);
    }
    const selectedImageOption = page.locator('#imageSelect');
    expect(await extractSelectedDisplayedValue(selectedImageOption)).toBe('Option 1 ');
  }, 60_000)
```

(I know the question was about C#, but it pops up when you search for the issue in general, and my attempts in NodeJs took me here.)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me! For those using TypeScript, `sel` in this example should be of type `HTMLSelectElement`

Comment: So, with the help from https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/discussions/12804, `const select = this.page.locator('#UserAddress_State');const testContent = await select.evaluate((node: HTMLSelectElement) => node.options[node.options.selectedIndex].textContent);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EvalOnSelectorAsync`, passing a CSS selector, and function expecting that element and returning the value of that element:

```
await page.EvalOnSelectorAsync<string>("#txtType", "el => el.value")
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the answers require the attribute "selected". What if there is no "selected" attribute?

```
<select id="element_id">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
<select>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35041558)